# How do I start my React App After I clone it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, testing, npm

I'm currently trying to deploy my app with netlify, but the problem is that I clone my app into my new computer, and now I'm getting some issues.

```
> todolistv2@1.0.0 start /Users/hvaandres/Documents/GitHub/TodoList_React
> npm run build

npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hvaandres/.npm/_logs/2021-03-04T06_19_54_506Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todolistv2@1.0.0 start: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the todolistv2@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hvaandres/.npm/_logs/2021-03-04T06_19_54_546Z-debug.log
```

I ran the following command npm install and I'm still getting the same issue. This is my debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'deploy' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.15.5
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeploy', 'deploy', 'postdeploy' ]
5 info lifecycle todolistv2@1.0.0~predeploy: todolistv2@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle todolistv2@1.0.0~deploy: todolistv2@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle todolistv2@1.0.0~deploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle todolistv2@1.0.0~deploy: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/hvaandres/Documents/GitHub/TodoList_React/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
9 verbose lifecycle todolistv2@1.0.0~deploy: CWD: /Users/hvaandres/Documents/GitHub/TodoList_React
10 silly lifecycle todolistv2@1.0.0~deploy: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run build && gh-pages -d build' ]
11 silly lifecycle todolistv2@1.0.0~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle todolistv2@1.0.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
13 verbose stack Error: todolistv2@1.0.0 deploy: `npm run build && gh-pages -d build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid todolistv2@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/hvaandres/Documents/GitHub/TodoList_React
16 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "deploy"
18 verbose node v14.15.5
19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error todolistv2@1.0.0 deploy: `npm run build && gh-pages -d build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the todolistv2@1.0.0 deploy script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "todolistv2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Todo-List",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run build"
    
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "todolist_project"
  ],
  "author": "Alan A. Haro",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

If someone can help me, I would really appreciate it. I'm just trying to learn more.

Comment: Error is `npm ERR! missing script: build`... says your package.json file doesn't have a `build` script? Did you mean to instead run `npm start`? Did you first `cd` into the project directory and install dependencies? Can you include your package JSON file in question?

Comment: I CD into my project, I run npm start and is giving me the same issue. I deleted the package-lock,json and run npm install. After that, I ran npm start one more time and I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: Same issue, you are missing the start command? Can we see your package.json file? If it's missing it's possibly just the simple CRA start command, i.e. `"start": "react-scripts start"`.

Comment: Ready, you should be able to see my package.json

Comment: Right, `npm run build` won't work because you also don't have a `build` script, the answer below steered you wrong. Try the start script I commented on above. I'm curious, where did you clone this repo from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1

you need a Node and Npm in your System
[Click here for installing Node.js and npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm)

### Step 2

delete **Package-lock.json** file

### Step 3

For installing Node Modules :

Run Command **npm install**

### Step 4

Run Command **npm start**

if not working then try Command

**npm run build**

or

**npm run dev**

if Still not working then open package.json file

and check

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run build" // your script code is "npm run build"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Your package JSON file appears to be missing both a `start` and `build` command. Add them back in. These are the defaults for newly created React apps using `create-react-app`. You also appear to be missing dependencies, namely `react` and `react-dom`.

```
{
  "name": "todolistv2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Todo-List",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "todolist_project"
  ],
  "author": "Alan A. Haro",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    ... add any other missing dependencies!!
  }
}
```